# Error says x is not a member of y, but it is

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a sp that I added to my linq designer, which generated the result class:

```
Partial Public Class web_GetTweetsByUserIDResult

    Private _userid As Integer

    Private _tweetid As Integer

    Private _TweeterFeed As String

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
    End Sub

    <Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_userid", DbType:="Int NOT NULL")>  _
    Public Property userid() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._userid
        End Get
        Set
            If ((Me._userid = value)  _
                        = false) Then
                Me._userid = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    <Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_tweetid", DbType:="Int NOT NULL")>  _
    Public Property tweetid() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._tweetid
        End Get
        Set
            If ((Me._tweetid = value)  _
                        = false) Then
                Me._tweetid = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    <Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_TweeterFeed", DbType:="NVarChar(100)")>  _
    Public Property TweeterFeed() As String
        Get
            Return Me._TweeterFeed
        End Get
        Set
            If (String.Equals(Me._TweeterFeed, value) = false) Then
                Me._TweeterFeed = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

However, in this one section of code where I am trying to use the "TweeterFeed" member of the result class I am getting the error, "Error   4 'TweeterFeed' is not a member of 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult(Of web_GetTweetsByUserIDResult)'."

My code in this section is, :

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetTweetsByUserID(ByVal userID As Integer) As List(Of SimpleTweet)
        Dim result As New List(Of SimpleTweet)
        Dim urlTwitter As String = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name={0}&count=20"
        Dim lq As New lqDFDataContext
        Dim var = lq.web_GetTweetsByUserID(userID).ToList()
        If Not var Is Nothing Then
            For Each twitterfeed In var

                Dim listURL As String = String.Format(urlTwitter, var.TweeterFeed)

                Dim tweetXML As XmlDocument = utils.GetXMLForURL(listURL)

                Dim tweetnodelist As XmlNodeList = tweetXML.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes

                For Each node As XmlNode In tweetnodelist
                    Dim tweet As New SimpleTweet
                    tweet.CreatedAt = node.SelectSingleNode("created_at").InnerText
                    tweet.HTMLText = utils.ReturnTextWithHRefLink(node.SelectSingleNode("text").InnerText)
                    tweet.ID = node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText
                    tweet.Name = node.SelectSingleNode("user/name").InnerText
                    tweet.ScreenName = node.SelectSingleNode("user/screen_name").InnerText
                    tweet.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("text").InnerText
                    tweet.UserID = node.SelectSingleNode("user/id").InnerText
                    tweet.ProfileImageURL = node.SelectSingleNode("user/profile_image_url_https").InnerText
                    result.Add(tweet)
                Next
            Next
        End If
        Return result
    End Function
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? As far as I see "TweeterFeed" is clearly a member of the class, I can't figure out why I would be getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `var.TweeterFeed` when you should be using `twitterFeed.TweeterFeed`. `twitterFeed` is *a* result extracted from `var` which is a *sequence* of results.

Using a more descriptive variable name than `var` would probably have made this clearer to you :)

Comment: Ah, yes! I feel silly now for having overlooked this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have this class

```
Public Class Tamano
    Private pWidth As Integer
    Private pHeight As Integer
    Public Property Width As Integer
    Public Property Height As Integer
End Class
```

I got the compilation error message `'Height' is not a member of 'Tamaño'` in IIS

To fix it, add Set and Get to the properties and it compiles.

```
Public Class Tamano
    Private pWidth As Integer
    Private pHeight As Integer
    Public Property Width As Integer
        Get
            Return pWidth
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            pWidth = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Height As Integer
        Get
            Return pHeight
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            pHeight = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

This might not be directly related to your question but It might help someone else.